# Safari stops drawing an element when flat on itself, unlike other browsers

Tags: html, css, sass, safari, frontend

I have had this problem lately with trying to draw 3D shapes on my site using CSS.

The intended result looks perfect on any other browser but Safari. Whether it's intentional by Apple or a poor effort of trying to optimize perfomance, when the drawn-on surface/element is flat on itself to the user, safari completely stops drawing that element. The problem can be better understood by viewing [this codepen.](https://codepen.io/Giannis-Nikolaou/pen/RwOWLLP)

If you're using Safari, and to my understanding, any browser in iOS devices, the issue will be visible, but on every other non-Apple controlled browser, the element will be drawn as expected.

The expected result was a drawn 3D object, but instead the object disappeared from the screen. A simple fix to this problem is to rotate the element by 1deg in any direction which will force it to not be flat on itself.

Does anyone know exactly why this happens? If so, can I do something to force Safari to draw that element?

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="tridiv">
    <div class="scene">
      <div class="shape cylinder-1 cyl-1">
        <div class="face bm"></div>
        <div class="face tp"></div>
        <div class="face side s0"></div>
        <div class="face side s1"></div>
        <div class="face side s2"></div>
        <div class="face side s3"></div>
        <div class="face side s4"></div>
        <div class="face side s5"></div>
        <div class="face side s6"></div>
        <div class="face side s7"></div>
        <div class="face side s8"></div>
        <div class="face side s9"></div>
        <div class="face side s10"></div>
        <div class="face side s11"></div>
        <div class="face side s12"></div>
        <div class="face side s13"></div>
        <div class="face side s14"></div>
        <div class="face side s15"></div>
        <div class="face side s16"></div>
        <div class="face side s17"></div>
        <div class="face side s18"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```scss
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

#tridiv {
  perspective: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 125%;

  &:hover {
    .cyl-1 {
      transform: translate3D(40px, 40px, 0) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3D(1.3, 1.3, 1.3);
      -webkit-transform: translate3D(40px, 40px, 0) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3D(1.3, 1.3, 1.3);
    }
  }
}

.scene,
.shape,
.face,
.face-wrapper,
.cr {
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.scene {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.shape {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  transform-origin: 50%;
}

.face,
.face-wrapper {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.face {
  background-size: 100% 100% !important;
  background-position: center;
}

.face-wrapper .face {
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.photon-shader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.side {
  left: 50%;
}

.cr,
.cr .side {
  height: 100%;
}

[class*="cylinder"] .tp {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%);
}

[class*="cylinder"] .bm {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-50%);
}

[class*="cylinder"] .tp,
[class*="cylinder"] .bm,
[class*="cylinder"] .tp .photon-shader,
[class*="cylinder"] .bm .photon-shader {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

[class*="cylinder"] .bm {
  top: 100%;
}

/* .cyl-1 styles */
.cyl-1 {
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95) 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95) 0s;
  top: 45px;
  transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0) rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(30deg) scale3D(1, 1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0) rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(30deg) scale3D(1, 1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 6em;
  height: 1.5em;
}

.cyl-1 .tp,
.cyl-1 .bm {
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
}

.cyl-1 .side {
  width: 1.0262229172794184em;
  height: 1.5em;
}

.cyl-1 .s0 {
  transform: rotateY(9.473684210526315deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s1 {
  transform: rotateY(28.421052631578945deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s2 {
  transform: rotateY(47.368421052631575deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s3 {
  transform: rotateY(66.3157894736842deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s4 {
  transform: rotateY(85.26315789473684deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s5 {
  transform: rotateY(104.21052631578947deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s6 {
  transform: rotateY(123.1578947368421deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s7 {
  transform: rotateY(142.10526315789474deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s8 {
  transform: rotateY(161.05263157894734deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s9 {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s10 {
  transform: rotateY(198.9473684210526deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s11 {
  transform: rotateY(217.89473684210526deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s12 {
  transform: rotateY(236.84210526315786deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s13 {
  transform: rotateY(255.78947368421052deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s14 {
  transform: rotateY(274.7368421052631deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s15 {
  transform: rotateY(293.6842105263158deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s16 {
  transform: rotateY(312.6315789473684deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s17 {
  transform: rotateY(331.578947368421deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .s18 {
  transform: rotateY(350.52631578947364deg) translate3D(-50%, 0, 2.975em);
}

.cyl-1 .face,
.cyl-1 .side {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.cyl-1 .tp {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.cyl-1 .bm {
  background: url(https://john-nik.com/icons/sass.svg) #ffffff;
}

.cyl-1 .side {
  background-color: #c63980;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
}
```